Why do i need to create a shallow copy of the Konva.Group children's array in order to use it in an angular template?
I am working on an image editor with Angular 17 and Konva. In Order to track and manipulate the Objects on the stage, I created a Service to share these object in a BehavorialSubject<Konva.Group> and a Component that subscribes to this group and then creates a list of the children array.
Service:
export class StackService {
  private stack: BehaviorSubject<Konva.Group>;
  public stack$: Observable<Konva.Group>;
  
  constructor(){
    let root = new Konva.Group({draggable: true});
    this.stack = new BehaviorSubject(root);
    this.stack$ = this.stack.asObservable();
  }     

}

Component TS:
[...]
this.stackService.stack$.subscribe((stack: Konva.Group) => {
  this.stack = stack;
});
[...]

Component Template:
<div *ngFor="let node of stack.getChildren()">
  {{node.attrs.name}}
</div>

Assume the stack is filled with some Konva.Shapes. When doing a console.log(this.stack.getChildren()) in the component's subscription, the output is:
Array(7) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
length: 0 // Why has it length 0 ?

Problem:
When calling *ngFor="let node of stack.getChildren()" in the template of my component, no node is shown.
Workaround:
But when I first create a shallow copy of the children-array when receiving the stack:
this.stackService.stack$.subscribe((stack: Konva.Group) => {
  this.stack = stack;
  this.nodes = stack.getChildren().slice();
});

And use this copy in the template:
<div *ngFor="let node of nodes">
  {{node.attrs.name}}
</div>

I get the list of names that I expect.
Question:
Why is that nessecary? Why can't I use the array directly?
[UPDATE]
I found the culprit. When receiving the stack in my stage component, I obviously need to add the new shapes to the stage. But instead of just adding the stack as a group, I added all children to the stage. This of course removed them from the stack group and added them to the stage, leaving the stack's children array empty after adding them to the stage.

is your component marked as onPush?

@Chellappanவ No, it uses default change detection
